# Populate mysql table with default values

Tags: mysql, sql, circular-buffer

i am looking for a mysql statment to create 50.000 entries in a simple mysql table.
The values can just be null or default value, except the primary key(autoincrement).

I want to build a circular buffer(see http://www.xarg.org/2009/09/fast-circular-buffer-in-mysql/) and for this i need a table with a fixed count of entries on the beginning.

Is this in general possible or do i have to do this on the common way with a loop?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: I don't think it's possible with an ordinary query, unless you have some other table with 50K entries that you can join with. You can do it with a stored procedure.

Comment: You could write a script in some other programming language, like `awk`, that will create the big `INSERT` statement and pipe it to `mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this with an `INSERT` is to type in 50,000 values, which I'm quite sure you do not want to do.

An alternative however, is to write a stored procedure that will do an insert on your table, and loop through 50,000 times.